# Content overflowing: auto height to tall for header div

Tags: html, css, height

I currently got a problem with content that is overflowing the header of my html. I tried using the css-property overflow, but setting it to hidden or auto is not what I am trying to achieve.
I don't want the overflowing content to be hidden, I want the height of my content fitting to the fixed hight of my header.

May anyone help?

Here is some sample code with the problem:

```css
body
{
  padding: 5%;
}
h1
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
h3
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
}
.Header
{
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class=Header>
        <h1>Header Sample Text</h1>
        <h3>Sub-Header Sample Text</h3>
        <p>Some Properties I have to display which are overflowing.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `margin` property to

```
h1,h3,p{
margin:5px 0px;}
```

for content set in fixed height

```css
body
{
  padding: 5%;
}
h1
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
h3
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
}
.Header
{
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}

h1,h3,p{
margin:5px 0px;}
```

```html
<div class=Header>
        <h1>Header Sample Text</h1>
        <h3>Sub-Header Sample Text</h3>
        <p>Some Properties I have to display which are overflowing.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a fixed height to your header and elements don't fit in it, it's normal that they overlap with the bottom border. You need either to change `height` to `min-height`, either to place those elements out of you fixed height div:

With min-height:

```css
body
{
  padding: 5%;
}
h1
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
h3
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
}
.Header
{
  min-height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class=Header>
        <h1>Header Sample Text</h1>
        <h3>Sub-Header Sample Text</h3>
        <p>Some Properties I have to display which are overflowing.</p>
</div>
```

Or outside the div:

```css
body
{
  padding: 5%;
}
h1
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
h3
{
  color: rgb(0, 32, 96);
}
.Header
{
  min-height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class=Header>
        <h1>Header Sample Text</h1>
        <h3>Sub-Header Sample Text</h3>
</div>
<p>Some Properties I have to display which are overflowing.</p>
```

Comment: But if I set the header height to min-height, the header grows taller.
What I seek to achieve is the content to become smaller.

Comment: @Ale Then if you really want your header to be fixed height, it's your job to calculate that everything fits in it, by setting explicitly all properties that can influence size, such as `margin`, `padding`, `font-size`, `line-height`, etc. Don't forget to do tests with browser zooming too, things can easily overflow a fixed-size element.